# How to use s3 location for oozie share lib

Tags: amazon-s3, bigdata, oozie

I am facing an issue where cluster needs to be scaled multiple times due to which oozie share lib gives missing block exception. Is it possible to store oozie share lib on s3 location instead of hdfs?

Comment: Which cluster you are using? Are you using Aws Emr?

Comment: Yes I am using aws emr cluster.

Comment: Is it possible if jar is unavailable on hdfs then copy it from s3 location to hdfs?

Comment: Ok, if you have a running cluster, you need to change the property `<property>
    <name>oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.system.libpath</name>
    <value>/user/newlocation</value>
  </property>` in oozie-site.xml and restart the oozie server. Another option is to specify the s3 location for share lib by setting the above property while spinning up the EMR cluster. Options will depend how you are spinning up the new cluster